# SQL set column with derived value

Tags: sql, database, sql-update

How to I set a column value to "1" where sum(price) >= 88

Eg: if sum(price) for customer A is more than or equal than 88, delivery will be updated as "Y"

customer table: name, price, delivery (i only listed out the important column)

My SQL query:

```
UPDATE  customer
SET delivery ='Y'
WHERE (SELECT SUM(price) FROM customer
GROUP BY name )>=88;
```

> Error: You can't specify target table "customer" for update in FROM clause

See attached table:

[image]

Comment: Most databases won't allow you to `UPDATE` selecting data from the same table you are updating.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result. A few rows will go a long way for us to understand your problem.

Comment: Most likely `(SELECT SUM(price) FROM customer GROUP BY name )` will return more than 1 rows, so what condition do you want to apply?

Comment: have added a photo of my table. not sure how to structure it to look nicer in stackoverflow so i took a snapshot instead. pardon me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any join between the table you're updating and your subselect. Your table doesn't really  have a key, but given what you've shown I'd do it like:

```
update Orders
set delivery = 'Y'
where Name in (SELECT NAME FROM 
    (SELECT NAME, SUM(PRICE) TOTAL_PRICE
    FROM ORDERS 
    GROUP BY NAME
    HAVING SUM(PRICE)> 88) A
    )
```

So basically it gets the Name of each customer and the sum or their order prices but only where the sum is over 88. It then just pulls out the Name from that subselect and only updates the rows where the name exists in the list of names for orders that sum over 88.

Answer (score 0):

Set the column to the value that you selecting from the table and don't group them.
`SET COLUMN_X = (SELECT SUM(price) FROM customer)`

Now you use your query and it looks cleaner

```
UPDATE  customer
SET delivery ='Y'
WHERE COLUMN_X = >=88;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which database you are using (or which version of it), so you may try if this *standard* SQL works on it:

```
with
x as (
  select name
  from customer
  group by name
  having sum(price) > 88
)
update customer c
set delivery = 'Y'
where name in (select name from x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the same thing @TheImpaler just posted, but with a subquery instead of a `CTE`.

Get the names that qualify first, then join to that list for the `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE t
  SET delivery = 'Y'
FROM
  #t AS t
JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      name
     ,SUM(price) AS total
    FROM
      #t
    GROUP BY
      name
    HAVING
      SUM(price) >= 88
  ) AS d
    ON
    d.name = t.name;
```

Here's a working Rextester: https://rextester.com/LQWE88535